# Link to inner section in Liferay Wiki portlet

Tags: liferay, wiki

In **Liferay Wiki** Portlet (version 6.2), using "*creole*" syntax, I can add a link to page simply typing its name inside square brackets like in Wikipedia.

```
[[New Page]]
```

How to add a link to a specific section of "*New Page*"?

In Wikipedia it's simply [[New Page#Section Title]], but in Liferay wiki I tried with same syntax but it re-directs me always a new page.

I see that in "New Page" aside "Section Title" heading is present a `#` that is a perma-link with the following pattern

```
mydomain.com/-/wiki/Main/New+Page/maximized#section-New+Page-Section+Title
```

I tried in many ways but... How to create a link to an inner section?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Liferay's Creole does not implement linking to a section. The creole help links to [this more complete documentation](http://www.wikicreole.org/wiki/Creole1.0) which also does not mention this as part of their markup.

You might have to extend the syntax on your own or use the full link.

Comment: for "full link" do you mean the absolute URL? It does not seem possible to insert relative one using Creole syntax

Comment: exactly. I guess that's your only option apart from pimping the Creole Engine.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the suggestion. In Wikipedia is possible, so do you know if using **MediaWiki** syntax in place of *Creole*, is possible inside *Liferay Wiki Portlet*? I tried but again without success